# Any 3D geometry algorithms library in Java?

Tags: java, 3d, geometry

I need a library, that could perform some geometry operations with objects in 3D, like:

- Find min distance between 2 triangles
- Intersect two polygons
- Intersect two wireframe objects and exctract their difference (hardest one).

Is there any such open-source library?

P.S. JTS is not an option, because it doesn't work with 3D :(

Comment: This is fairly far outside my expertise, but what about a physics engine like JMonkey?  http://jmonkeyengine.org/  A cursory review suggests it would support some of these features, though the model definition side may be overkill for what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, it seams they really provide such functionality. I'll try to crearte simple test, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Java3D](http://java3d.java.net/).